# Background Margin-top effect with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background

I would like to achieve a lovely margin-top effect for my background, where am I going wrong with this code?

```
body {
    background-image: url("index images/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center, 90%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Here's a sample of what I would like to have http://mailchimp.com/pricing/

Much help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What `margin-top` effect ? You mean the `nav` disappearing on scroll down ?

Comment: that white top is header not background margin top

Comment: I think you have a redundant comma there.. `background-position: center 90%;` should work. Also, `url("index images/background.png");` is not the actual image path is it? :)

Comment: @Vucko - nothing as fancy as that, just a gap between the background and the top of the screen.

Comment: @subarachnid - yes that is the real path, why? I removed the redundant comma, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: then `background-position: center 50px;` you can change this value to 100px or 20px as needed.

Comment: @Vucko: does the image show up at all? I think the path should be `url("index%20images/background.png");` You can't have spaces in filenames.

Comment: @user2179119 you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VCBqr/)?

Comment: yes the image shows up, but duly noted for the filename.

Comment: @Anjum yes it works! I've set it to background-position: center 10px

Comment: thanks @Anjum, and to everyone else, you have all helped me out a lot! :)

Comment: @Vucko - not quite like that, just like the example I showed but without the fancy disappearing animation. Thanks for your help and for pointing out my spacing errors, I'm sure that would have caused some problems further down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-position: center 50px;
```

you can change value as needed like 10px 100px